# "Size cannot be known at compilation time" error when using flat_map

Tags: rust

I have a piece of code as follows:

```
pub fn is_valid_sudoku(board: Vec<Vec<char>>) -> bool {
    let block_it = |i, j| board[i..i + 3].iter().flat_map(move |row| {
        row[j..j + 3]
    });
    // Rest of the code...
}
```

In this code, I encountered an error message that says "the size for values of type [char] cannot be known at compilation time."
To resolve this error, I needed & before row[j..j+3] like this: &row[j..j+3], and the error disappeared.

row is of type &Vec, so row[j..j+3] should be of type &[char] , so why I need to add & to row[j..j+3] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter whether row is of type `Vec<char>` or `&Vec<char>`, `row` will be auto-[deref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#impl-Deref-for-Vec%3CT,+A%3E)'ed into `&[char]`, and then [the `[]` operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/struct.Range.html#impl-SliceIndex%3C%5BT%5D%3E-for-Range%3Cusize%3E) will be invoked on that, meaning that `row[j..j+3]` is of type `[char]`, as the compiler tells you in the error message.

Side note: You can also write `&row[j..][..3]`.

Comment: thanks for your answer Caesar, I totally forgot about "match ergonomics" .

Comment: Don't think that's what's going on here.

Comment: yes , I got it wrong , and I think no need to auto-deref here, because as you said the [] operator applied to row will always result in [char] whatever type of row is ( Vec<char> or &Vec<char> ).